# Fonts are blocked by firefox Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-origin-read-blocking

When I open my html file in browser , fonts blocked by firefox , I don't have any problem on other browsers and this happen just on mozila firefox.

Error :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the 
remote resourceat file:///C:/Users/SajjaD/Desktop/PdfCar%20New%20Theme/Theme/PdfCar%20V2/fonts/WebY ekan.woff. (Reason: CORS request not http).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the 
remote resource at file:///C:/Users/SajjaD/Desktop/PdfCar%20New%20Theme/Theme/PdfCar%20V2/fonts/font awesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0. (Reason: CORS request not http).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the 
remote resource at file:///C:/Users/SajjaD/Desktop/PdfCar%20New%20Theme/Theme/PdfCar%20V2/fonts/font awesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0. (Reason: CORS request not http).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the 
remote resource at file:///C:/Users/SajjaD/Desktop/PdfCar%20New%20Theme/Theme/PdfCar%20V2/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0. (Reason: CORS request not http).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the 
remote resource at file:///C:/Users/SajjaD/Desktop/PdfCar%20New%20Theme/Theme/PdfCar%20V2/fonts/dinar.woff. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

Comment: This is going to be fixed in Firefox 68.0.2: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting a CORS error is likely because you are loading your font's via a network path `file:///C:/...` rather than an actual HTTP request.

`disallows reading the 
remote resourceat file:`

This message essentially means we found that you had something to load but we are not allowed to access it because it is a local file resource on the network drive in which we do not have permission to request.

You can probably bypass this error by correctly referencing your resources, so rather than pointing to `file:///C://` you would start from the root folder that contains the website and request them from there e.g. `../website/assets/fonts/font-file.ttf`. But this is a wild guess on the basis that I have no idea what tech stack you are developing with.

You can read more about it here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp